# Why is my VS Code not rendering graphics windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, rendering, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use pygame to render a TicTacToe game, but it appears that when I run the code nothing happens. But, it looks to me that the code is running perfectly fine, it is just that the pygame graphics window is not popping up.

After a fair amount of troubleshooting, I believe that the problem resides with my VS Code permissions and not in the code itself. I tried to run the following code

```
import turtle
geoff = turtle.Turtle()

geoff.forward(100)

input("Press any key to exit ...")
```

To see if the graphics window would pop up for this code, but it doesn't.

Please help me figure out how to get my graphics window working.

Kind regards,

Comment: Does this help? end_fill()
done()

Answer (score 0):

Try to install tkinter. If you are in you venv activated:

```bash
pip install tk
```

else:

```bash
your/path/to/python3 -m pip install tk
```